# PHP MySQL PDO selecting rows on array with id's

Tags: php, arrays, select, pdo

I stored some multiple id values from a form[] in a session.

I tried to use these id's within a mysql pdo database query as follow:

```
$noot = str_repeat("?,", count($_SESSION['uniqueID'])-1) . "?";

$printen = 1;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT ru.GB,g.Name,g.Address,g.Place,ri.Ricode,lo.nr,lo.uniqueID,GROUP_CONCAT(ru.control SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS control,GROUP_CONCAT(ru.BestEmail SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS email,GROUP_CONCAT(ru.ont_info SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS ont,GROUP_CONCAT(ru.sup SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS Lev,GROUP_CONCAT(ru.OrderID SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS orderID,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ru.rID SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS RID,GROUP_CONCAT(ru.Pack SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS packet FROM rutrans AS ru JOIN routes AS ri ON ru.rID = ri.rID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN lock AS lo
             ON ri.Ricode = lo.ricode AND ru.GB = lo.location
    LEFT OUTER JOIN gbc AS g
             ON ru.GB = g.CodeB          
WHERE  lo.uniqueID IN ($noot)");

$query->execute($_SESSION['uniqueID']);

//$data = $query->fetchAll();
```

And try to get the results like this:

```
foreach($queryRT as $rowRT) { 

 (I echo database results within a table for each row here,... or try to do this)

}
```

The following error occures:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in

When I add

```
$data = $query->fetchAll();
```

to the query the page is totally blank.

When I try something to show like this:

`print_r($data);`

Only the following is being displayed on the page:

> Array ( )

When I try something like this:

`print_r($_SESSION['uniqueID']);`

It shows the array as follow:

```
Array ( [B1601222016164345] => B1601222016164345 
        [B1601222016161121] => B1601222016161121 
        [B1601262126474345] => B1601262126474345 
        [B1602011856554345] => B1602011856554345 
        [B1602101921434345] => B1602101921434345 
        [Z1602102002034345] => Z1602102002034345
        [Z1602102026544345] => Z1602102026544345 
      )
```

Obviously I am doing something totally wrong. 
Is there anybody who would have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: "invalid parameter number"? check that `$noot` is actually being produced properly. you maybe be generating (say) `?,?,?`, but then providing only 2 values for those placeholders.

Comment: As the error suggests you are passing the wrong number of arguments. Your'e setting as many ?  as placeholder for your values and then give one array as Argument. Pass the values from the session each as own argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SESSION['uniqueID']` needs to have numbers for its index if you are using `?` as placeholders.

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

> The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was silently ignored.

Try this:

```
$query->execute(array_values($_SESSION['uniqueID']));
```

Comment: Hi,$query->execute(array_values($_SESSION['uniqueID']));

Comment: Hi,

Thank you all,  I understand it a bit. 

$query->execute(array_values($_SESSION['uniqueID']));

shows indeed more results when using print_r($data), though it looks a bit odd, probably caused by the way the query is set up, with all the joints.
It worked without "WHERE" though.

If I may ask, is there also any clever way to get the same sort of result from this as I normally have when using 

foreach($query as $row) { 

echo specific row data

}

kind regards

Comment: Not that I can think of. I think your way of generating a placeholder is pretty clever already.

Comment: Hi, thank you all  for the insight. And to help me further Dave.
Kind regards!